# Graph theory prove there is no universal vertex on path

Tags: graph-theory

I had a quick question:

If I have a cycle on graph $G$ that contains the edges $a$ and $b$ and another cycle on the graph $G$ that contains the edges $b$ and $c$, how can I show that there exists no vertex $u$ on $G$ such that every path from an end of $a$ to an end of $c$ contains $u$.  My textbook says the proof is immediate but doesn't seem the least bit trivial to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose an end $x$ of $a$ that is not $u$.

From $x$ walk along the $a,b$-cycle to an end $y$ of $b$ that is not $u$ (you have two ways around the circle, so you can talk a walk that avoids $u$).

From $y$ walk along the $b,c$-cycle to an end $z$ of $c$ that is not $u$ (you have two ways around the circle, so you can talk a walk that avoids $u$).

Now you have a walk that avoids $u$ and this walk contains a path that avoids $u$.

ADDED ON REQUEST: Every $v,w$-walk contains a $v,w$-path.

We prove this by induction on the length of the walk.
The induction base, length 0, is obvious.

So let $P=v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_n=w$ be a $v,w$-walk of length $n>0$.
If $P$ is a path we are done.
If $P$ is not a path some vertex must be repeated, say $v_i=v_j$, $i<j$.

But then $v=v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_i=v_j,v_{j+1},\ldots,v_n=w$ is a shorter $v,w$-walk.
By the induction hypothesis it contains a $v,w$-path which must also be contained in $P$.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that if there exists a walk that doesn't contain $u$ then there is a path that also doesn't contain $u$.  Can you make this argument more rigorously?